Is price really the cost of hedging?
Assume a vanilla option with 1y expiry. The total vol in 1yr is 20 bps, the vol in first 6 months is 5 bps. The price is created by BS(20 bps).
But is this price the correct cost of hedging? Will I not leak PnL in the first 6 months according to the difference between implied and realized vol, and leak in the opposite direction in the other 6 months? Is there a guarantee that the two will cancel out exactly, and how can we show it?
If there is still a PnL leak after pricing the call correctly, then price must not capture the cost of hedging?

The statement that the correct price is the cost of hedging is tautological: if you experience a profit or loss (for example due to a change in IV while you were assuning it constant, or some other factor) then it shows that you were not properly hedging against this factor. You need to improve your hedging.

A correct estimation of cost of hedging should not leak PnL, right?

Let’s make the scenario even more extreme to make the point clear: assume that the 1yr implied vol is $\sigma$, and that zero vol is expected for the next 6 months.  Also assume interest rates are zero for simplicity.  Then I claim (1) the price of the option at any time is given by the terminal distribution (we don’t care how the vol is distributed over time) (2) during the first 6 months, the quantity $\sigma^2 (T-t)$ is stationary, so the annualized implied vol gradually creeps up as time goes on. (3) thus what happens is that, assuming you update the implied vol every day , your option price and delta are correct (depending on the terminal distribution only) BUT your time decay calculated at any constant vol is wrong.  During the first 6 months , the daily time decay should be zero (proof : examine the BS formula when $\sigma^2 (T-t)$ is constant).  The missing term is the Vega p/l when implied vol accretes slightly every day. Hence yes, if you naively calculate time decay you will experience positive leak over the first six months.  Main point is that as long as you use the correct terminal distribution you will calculate correct deltas and will just have a theta miscalculation.
Now, if you were to actually be even more naive and just use a constant vol for the whole period, you will be using the wrong terminal distribtion and therefore you will miscalculate the price and the delta.  During the first six months your model shows a time decay which does not occur, so you will show a positive drift relative to that. In the second six months the actual time decay is faster than your model because the vol you are using is too low.  But these errors of the first six months and the second six months are not guaranteed to offset because they are path dependent (error is largest when option is close to the strike).
Bottom line : if you correctly update the vol daily, the errors offset but if you use a constant vol they don’t.

" if you were to actually be even more naive and just use a constant vol for the whole period, you will be using the wrong terminal distribtion and therefore you will miscalculate the price and the delta" - would you miscalculate price if you use the correct annual vol and just spread it constantly over time? I think not, as you said we don't care how vol is distributed. Am I missing something?

I guess you'll get the initial price right but price at every other time wrong (and this Greeks wrong). And so the statement "initial price captures cost of hedging"  may be incorrect but "price(t,S(t))" captures cost of hedging is right.
